# using int counter in array name

Tags: c, arrays, int

In C I'm wondering if I can use an `int` as a counter to select an array from my list of arrays. If not how would you suggest getting around this? Sorry the code might explain it better:

edit: Sorry i should have clarified by saying that inputchar is a single character, im trying to see if inputchar is a letter in any of the words in the arrays

```
int i;

char word0[] ={'c','a','c','h','e'};
char word1[] ={'i','n','t','e','l'};
char word2[] ={'e','t','h','e','r','n','e','t'};
char word3[] ={'g','i','g','a','b','y','t','e'};
char word4[] ={'l','i','n','u','x'};

for (input = 0;input<i;input++)
{
    if (inputchar==word(i)[input] /*this is the problem here, i want to use the int (i) to chose the array, i is randomized before this in the program */
    {
        w(i)[input]=inputchar;
        lc++;
        printf("You guessed correct! continue on word master");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you just need an array of arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest change to what you have is to create an array of pointers to each of your existing arrays:

```
char *words[] = { word0, word1, word2, word3, word4 };
```

Because your arrays aren't nul-terminated, you will also need to know their lengths, and you can't access that from `words`:

```
size_t wordlengths[] = { sizeof(word0), sizeof(word1), sizeof(word2), sizeof(word3), sizeof(word4) };
```

But, if your code doesn't actually rely on having 5 different writeable arrays of different sizes, containing non-terminated character data, then you might be able to do better.

Comment: this is great! thank you.I'm only starting out with pointers so im not too sure, what i have done is implemented your code and changed the if statement to if (inputchar ==*word(i)[input] and its giving me an error about calling to undefined function 'word', any ideas?

Comment: You need to change word(i)[input] to word[i][input].

Comment: changed but the same problem :( except now its undefined symbol :S

Comment: @user1842845 Try `words[i][input]` if you copied Steve's code.

Comment: *facepalm* i feel like such an idiot xD thanks a million Daniel :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an array of strings (pointers)?

```
char* words[5];
```

Then assign the individual strings:

```
words[0] = "cache";
words[1] = "intel";
words[2] = "ethernet";
words[3] = "gigabyte";
words[4] = "linux";
```

Now you can access it with an array index:

```
words[i][input]
```

Comment: @PaulR Yeah, you're right. I just wasn't sure why the OP was assigning `inputchar` after testing for equality.

Comment: That's not an array of arrays, of course, it's an array of pointers. But it might do the job.

Comment: Hard to tell - he might only need read-only data but it's not really clear from the question.

Comment: to clear it up inputchar was a character variable entered by the user, its a hangman exercise for college

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to change:

```
char word0[] ={'c','a','c','h','e'};
char word1[] ={'i','n','t','e','l'};
char word2[] ={'e','t','h','e','r','n','e','t'};
char word3[] ={'g','i','g','a','b','y','t','e'};
char word4[] ={'l','i','n','u','x'};
```

to e.g.:

```
char word[5][10] = { "cache",
                     "intel",
                     "ethernet",
                     "gigabyte",
                     "linux" };
```

and then you can write e.g.

```
    if (inputchar == word[i][input])
        ...
```

Comment: Be careful with the curly braces! They kill syntax!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest workaround is an array of arrays:

```
char word[][9] = {"cache", "intel", "ethernet", "gigabyte", "linux"};
```

This declares `word` as a 5-element array of 9-element arrays of `char`; the 5 is determined from the number of items in the initializer, and the 9 is required to hold the longest strings (8 characters plus the 0 terminator).

This does mean that there's some unused space in the first, second, and fifth string, but for an exercise like this that's probably not a big deal.  If you were dealing with several thousand strings, it would be better to declare an array of pointers, then allocate each string separately so that you're only using as much memory as each string needs:

```
char *word[N]; // for N strings;
...
word[i] = malloc(length_of_string_for_this_element + 1);
if (word[i])
  strcpy(word[i], string_for_this_element);
```

When you're done, you would need to free that memory for each word:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  free(word[i]);
```

Either way, you would access a specific character as

```
word[i][input]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this (an array of pointers), If you don't need to modify the items.

```
const char *words[ 5 ] = { "cache", "intel", "ethernet", "gigabyte", "linux" };
```

This is how it works:

[image: How it works]
[image]

This is an example from C, How to Program by Deitel & Deitel.

Comment: What if he wants to modify his data though ?

Comment: He didn't say he wanted to, I assumed he doesn't want

Comment: He's trying to modify the data inside the second pair of brackets.

Comment: @JosuéMolina I am not so sure of that, cause he wants to compare only.